# whmcs charset & template

Tags: character-encoding, whmcs

I have one problem with charset, I need `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1`.

I tried there to set up it:

[image: screen whmcs klick]

(whmcs language )

but it is not working.

I tied this:

[image: drawing]

But it still show at homepage this:

[image: Homepage]

Client area is working.

I just need this at homepage Ä Ö Ü ß *

I hope someone can help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it without ISO-8859-1? After removing it you may need to re-type the  strings again. UTF-8 should work, we use it with Arabic and it is perfect.

Check database and tables, they should be UTF-8 as well, and there are tools to convert tables to UTF-8. check this script:
https://gist.github.com/wesamly/2c994e6bd4466151b60b

Note: Backup your database before converting.

Comment: yes my database is UTF-8 I tried everything. UTF-8 is not working with german

Comment: Try update that string from phpMyAdmin, but keep only UTF8 in WHMCS, and make sure your template head section have <meta charset="{$charset}" />. 
And by the way, UTF-8 works for all languages, I just mentioned Arabic because we have no latin characters at all, and it works.

Comment: nope its not working <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="{$charset}" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{if $kbarticle.title}{$kbarticle.title} - {/if}{$pagetitle} - {$companyname}</title>

    {include file="$template/includes/head.tpl"}

    {$headoutput}

</head>

Comment: What is the table and database chartset?

Comment: damn sry, It is UTF-8